# What is the English for French "plan" (in an academic presentation)

Tags: word-choice

What is the English for French "plan" in an academic presentation?

For instance:

> **Plan**
>
> 1. Introduction
> 2. Data and methodology
> 3. Results
> 4. Conclusion

This meaning of French "plan" is very pervasive in the French education/academic system (in Google search, 33 000 000 for "[**plan** de la dissertation](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=plan%20de%20la%20dissertation)" ("dissertation" is a specific term for 'high school essay') ('high school essay's plan');  394 000 000 results for "[**plan** de la présentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=plan%20de%20la%20pr%C3%A9sentation&client=firefox-b-d&ei=WUGTY9f6Hurm2roPmv2BgAY&oq=plan%20de%20la%20pr%C3%A9sent&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAxgAMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6CAgAEBYQHhAPSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUPoJWMsSYIkYaAJwAXgBgAGlA4gB1gmSAQkxLjQuMS4wLjGYAQCgAQHIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)" ('presentation plan').

Two problems: (1) this meaning is not really described in French dictionaries (2) I can't find a good translation in English dictionaries/translation tools

(1) French dictionaries

In French, the word "plan" covers many meanings. In fact, in the [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plan), it corresponds to 3 different nouns. The 1st one has 6 meanings, and the 2nd one (which concerns us here, has 8 meanings).
Here is my translation of those 8 meanings from the wiktionary :

> 1. Graphic representation of a construction 2. Map 3. **Organisation of a project** 4. Previsional economic organisation of a country 5.
>    Event after a preparation 6. Intention, purpose 7. Musical structure 8. Sexual meeting

Bolded is the meaning which concerns us here.

In the French dictionary TLFI, "plan" is also [described](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?19;s=3359110920;r=1;nat=;sol=8;) as having lots of meanings. One that corresponds to the meaning which concerns here is, bolded (my translation) :

> B.1. **Written project, containing an ordered series of operations,
> in order to achieve an action or a series of actions**

(2) English dictionaries/translation tools

I searched on [linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=plan%20de%20la%20pr%C3%A9sentation) but I can't find.
Google translate gives ["plan of the presentation"](https://translate.google.fr/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=le%20plan%20de%20la%20pr%C3%A9sentation&op=translate), but I am not sure.

Comment: If you ask for the English equivalent of a word in another language you must explain at length and in English the meaning and connotations of the idea the foreign word expresses.  Otherwise your question comes under the category of "translation", which the [Tour] indicates is off-topic.

Comment: @David I tried to edit my questions following the rules. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a real dictionary like Harrap's or Larousse? Instead of this linguee and google shite? By the way, un plan élaboré is not an elaborated project, it is a written project.

Comment: [Reverso](https://www.reverso.net/text-translation#sl=fra&tl=eng&text=plan) is very good at giving varieties of translation -in actual sentences.

Comment: @Mitch Yes indeed, I just tried with "plan de la présentation", it gives "layout of the presentation" (I suppose it is incorrect), but I tried with "plan de la présentation académique" and it gives "outline of academic presentation". In all due fairness, I re-tried Deepl with "plan de la présentation académique" and it also gives the correct "outline of the academic presentation". Thank you for the recommandation of Reverso's machine translation tool (I didn't know it)! I really appreciate the concrete examples it provides below the translation window

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your correction on "written project", I made the modification. Thank you for indicating me the Larousse French-English dictionary. In the case of "plan", as for the online version (https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais), it gives poor results. I am sure the print version would be far better though.

Comment: @starckman None of these tools are perfect, so you always need to use judgement. But reverso does benefit from having many examples (maybe some aren't exactly the right thing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Outline**:

a general sketch, account, or report, indicating only the main features, as of a book, subject, or project

1. Structure.
2. Breakdown

[www.dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com)

Pick the one you like.

Comment: Just to be sure: "plan" is not possible?

Comment: @starckman: *plan* would be unidiomatic if you used it for the structure of an academic presentation, and in most cases, *breakdown* would be even worse. But *outline* and *structure* are both good.

Comment: Thank you very much Ricky and @Peter Shor. I'm glad I double checked on this forum.

Comment: @PeterShor "plan would be unidiomatic if you used it for the structure of an academic presentation" must I understand that "plan" can be used for the structure of something else ? (another type of writing, or presentation?)

Comment: You can use plan for the structure of a house, or a city. Probably not for writing or presentation (it's possible that you could use it for a film, which is a much more complicated object).

Comment: If you are robbing a bank or setting out a project, you would use a plan. For presentations and meetings, *agenda* is also common.

Comment: @PeterShor, if you're drawing a house, a *plan* is specifically a view as if from overhead. A view of (for example) the front of the building is an *elevation*.